# I can't get my raspberry pi to download the library files for Pixyusb2

Tags: pi-3, camera

So I'm trying to get a pixy camera to connect to my pi for a school project, and whenever I run this code

sudo apt-get install git libusb-1.0-0-dev g++ build-essential

I get this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.6)
g++ is already the newest version (4:8.3.0-1+rpi2).
g++ set to manually installed.
libusb-1.0-0-dev is already the newest version(2:1.0.22-2).
Suggested packages:
    git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc get-el git-email git-gui gitk 
gitweb git-cvs git-mediawiki git-sun
The following new packages will be installed
git git-man libcurl13-gnutls liberror-perl
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
Need to get 6,137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 32.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf 
libcurl13-gnutls armhf 7.64.0-4+deb10u1
  Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libcurl13-gnutls_7.64.0-4+deb10u1_armhf.deb - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 72.5.72.15 80]
Err:2 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf liberror-perl all 0.17027-2
  Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/liberror-perl_0.17027-2_all.deb - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 72.5.72.15 80]
Err:3 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf 
git-man all 1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3
  Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/git-man_1%3a2.20.1-2+deb10u3_all.deb - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 72.5.72.15 80]
Err:4 http://mirror.sjc02.svwh.net/raspbian/raspbian buster/main armhf 
git armhf 1:2.20.1-2+deb10u3
  Could not open file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/git_1%3a2.20.1-2+deb10u3__armhf.deb - open (30: Read-only file system) [IP: 72.5.72.15 80]
W: not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-fronted
W: not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - Setup APTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W:chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - Setup APTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - Setup APTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - Setup APTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.apt-aquire-privus-test.7ArC2t - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.apt-aquire-privus-test.4uQtyy - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.apt-aquire-privus-test.Vhtr5C - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.apt-aquire-privus-test.ehtbCH - IsAccessibleBySandboxUser (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/libcurl13-gnutls_7.64.0-4+deb10u1_armhf.deb - Prepare files (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/liberror-perl_0.17027-2_all.deb - Prepare files (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/git-man_1%3a2.20.1-2+deb10u3_all.deb - Prepare files (30: Read-only file system)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/archives/partial//git_1%3a2.20.1-2+deb10u3__armhf.deb - Prepare files (30: Read-only file system)
```

Comment: Can't see your error it requires a password. Just paste the text (not a picture).

Comment: I just Fixed it for you